# ViewModel creation blocking UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, winrt-xaml, uwp

In my XAML UI I have a listview which contains a list of complex objects. These complex objects have an async initialization method which loads in the data (downloads an image, formats the text, etc).

Here's the setup (pseudo code):

```
public class PageViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items;

  public async Task InitializeAsync()
  {
      var models = await GetModelsAsync();
      List<Task> initTasks = new List<Task>();
      foreach(var model in models)
      {
         var vm = new ItemViewModel(model)
         initTasks.Add(vm.InitializeAsync());
         Items.Add(vm);
      }

      await Task.WhenAll(initTasks);
  }
}
```

The issue i'm seeing is that it seems like the UI thread is being blocked and unresponsive until all the tasks have completed which is confusing me. All my async complex logic is in an awaitable task.

This lead me to experiment with the only other logic here, the creation of the view model. The issue seems to dissapear when I wrap the following code in a Task.Run:

```
var vm = Task.Run(() => new ItemViewModel(item))
```

This surprised me because there's very little to no logic in the ViewModel constructor which is why I was fine initially putting it on the UI thread.

Does anyone have thoughts on why I would see the UI thread block here? Do you have any code suggestions?

Comment: What is the real code? You're adding VMs to a list of Tasks. Have your tried debugging or profiling?

Comment: `public Task InitializeAsync()` should be `public async Task InitializeAsync()`. Or is this just an inaccuracy in pseudocode?

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis Not important.

Comment: Your `InitializeAsync` seems very very wrong. Why does `ItemViewModel` inherit from `Task`. If not, could you fix your code? I suspect that `initTasks.Add(vm);` does not actually exist in your code.

Comment: Sorry bad typo: I meant to add the InitializeAsync method to the init tasks list. I updated the psedo code in the question.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT - see updated fix to my code - I meant to add the initialize method of the item view model (not the VM itself) to the initTasks list. Yes I did profile it, the only thing that really stood out to me was a quite a bit of garbage collecting going on, although that could be just my low experience level with the VS profiling tools.

Comment: Can you share the little code in `ItemViewModel` constructor, which in your opinion is causing the UI blocking?

Comment: I suspect the code in `InitializeAsync()` is causing the blocking. Could you show us that code? Does it produce any warnings?

Comment: @DamirArh there's nothing in the constructor other than setting some strings and such which is what's confusing me so much.

Comment: @svick I don't think the issue is in InitializeAsync() even when I comment out that code, the UI thread blocks

Comment: May I recommend you consider http://aka.ms/template10? This framework calls OnNavigatedTo in the view-model before the Page loads in the first place, but continues to allow for rendering of the XAML pipeline. It's very effective and might help. Just an idea. Template 10 is very popular and well supported.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure where you are calling your init() but you should be (unless you use an intelligent framework that automatically calls it for you) callingit from your Page OnNavTo override, like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage() { InitializeComponent(); }

    MainPageViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as MainPage;

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        await DataContext.InitAsync();
    }
}

public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public Task InitAsync()
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

As an aside, I don't recommend you load your models in parallel, but instead in series because of performance on low-powered devices. Make sense? I should not make a noticeable difference to your user, bur your app will not lock if the generation is costly.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jerry. Yes I'm binding to the OnNavigatedTo event in my page and executing the InitializeAsync method from there. So in your example above, I'm performing a bunch of async operations in the InitAsync method (all which do not block the UI thread) and I also create child viewmodels (on the UI thread) which is what's seeming to block it. It's really confounding to me why simple VM creations on the UI thread are causing it to block.